# Angular meteor not calling main.ts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Hi we are following the angular meteor tutorials:
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping

We are trying to create the main entry point (main.ts) but it never seems to call the main.ts file. Its calls the rest of them but not that. Why is that are these tutorials outdated because I have to change one or two things before my self . Here is our repo so far please any help would be great.

https://github.com/yawlhead91/Socially-Meteor-App-.git